# Скриншотилка Ashot не игнорирует элементы на странице

Tags: java, selenium

Ссылка на тулзу https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot
При создании скриншота с результатом сравнения, на нем отмечены "красным" те элементы, что должны были в теории игнорироваться. Что я делаю не так?

Код:

```
//Создаем Эталонный скриншот
Screenshot ExpectedDir = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100)).takeScreenshot(driver); 
ImageIO.write(ExpectedDir.getImage(), "png", new 
File("Screenshot\\Expected.png"));

//Создаем фактический скриншот
  Screenshot actualScreenshot = new AShot()
    .shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100))
    .addIgnoredElement(By.cssSelector(".banner.g-zindex-top[data-banner-id='fp_new_top']"))
    .addIgnoredElement(By.cssSelector(".banner.g-banner__newsfeed[data-banner-id='firstpage_left2']"))
    .addIgnoredElement(By.cssSelector(".banner.g-banner__padding[data-banner-id='firstpage_graph2_new']"))
    .takeScreenshot(driver); 

ImageIO.write(actualScreenshot.getImage(), "png", new File("Screenshot\\Actual.png"));

ExpectedDir.setIgnoredAreas(actualScreenshot.getIgnoredAreas());  

ImageDiff diff = new ImageDiffer().makeDiff(ExpectedDir, actualScreenshot);                          

diff.getDiffSize();          

File diffFile = new File("Screenshot\\markedImages.png");
ImageIO.write(diff.getMarkedImage(), "png", diffFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что у меня шапка прикреплена к верху экрана и не пропадает при скроллинге страницы. а висит сверху. я изначально думал ну и пусть. буду так делать скриншоты. но нет... это оказалось критичным. из-за этого не игнорируются динамические элементы в самой шапке. ..ну.. или как то так... спасибо =)

закрепил следующим кодом:

Summary
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".topline.fixed"));
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'position: static!important;')",element1);